App Script G Sheets Auto-Email on Specific Cell Edit
I have four tabs that contains similar sets of information.  When a dropdown is set to "NEW" in Tab 1, I would like it to email a specific person.  The problem I am getting is when Tab 2 is edited in the same area, it sends the same email.
What I would like to do is have each tab send an email to a different person when an edit is made only in that specific tab.
Example: Tab 1 is edited > email is sent to Person 1; Tab 2 is edited > email is sent to Person 2
Right now, when either Tab 1 or Tab 2 is edited, it sends an email to the same person.
I am sure I will need a new script for Tab 2, Tab 3, etc., but I want to figure out how to have only Tab 1's edits send an email.
Here is the script I am working with:
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 

  // EVENT VARIABLES 
  let range = e.range; 
  let row = e.range.getRow(); 
  let col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 

  let projectName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); 
  let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bAJ0Asma4lX1tW3HYezW_Al6llkpaIKWSLptfjV-pAI/edit#gid=712318935"

  if ( col == 1 && cellValue == "NEW") {
    // Browser.msgBox('It works'); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'email1@email.com',
      'Staff Overview Update',
      "There has been an update to the Staff Overview sheet requiring your attention: " + url + '&range=' + cellLocation,
      {name: 'Team Leader'}
    ); 
  }; 

}


try:
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  let sheetName = sheet.getName(); // Get the name of the active sheet

  // EVENT VARIABLES 
  let range = e.range; 
  let row = e.range.getRow(); 
  let col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 

  let projectName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); 
  let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bAJ0Asma4lX1tW3HYezW_Al6llkpaIKWSLptfjV-pAI/edit#gid=712318935";

  if (col == 1 && cellValue == "NEW") {
    let recipientEmail;
    
    // Determine the recipient based on the sheet name
    if (sheetName === "Tab 1") {
      recipientEmail = 'email1@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 2") {
      recipientEmail = 'email2@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 3") {
      recipientEmail = 'email3@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 4") {
      recipientEmail = 'email4@email.com';
    }
    
    if (recipientEmail) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        recipientEmail,
        'Staff Overview Update',
        "There has been an update to the " + sheetName + " sheet requiring your attention: " + url + '&range=' + cellLocation,
        {name: 'Team Leader'}
      ); 
    }
  }
}


UPDATE
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  let sheetName = sheet.getName(); // Get the name of the active sheet
  let sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); // Get the unique ID of the active sheet

  // EVENT VARIABLES 
  let range = e.range; 
  let row = e.range.getRow(); 
  let col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 

  let projectName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); 
  let baseUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bAJ0Asma4lX1tW3HYezW_Al6llkpaIKWSLptfjV-pAI/edit";

  if (col == 1 && cellValue == "NEW") {
    let recipientEmail;
    
    // Determine the recipient based on the sheet name
    if (sheetName === "Tab 1") {
      recipientEmail = 'email1@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 2") {
      recipientEmail = 'email2@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 3") {
      recipientEmail = 'email3@email.com';
    } else if (sheetName === "Tab 4") {
      recipientEmail = 'email4@email.com';
    }
    
    if (recipientEmail) {
      let url = `${baseUrl}#gid=${sheetId}&range=${cellLocation}`;
      MailApp.sendEmail(
        recipientEmail,
        'Staff Overview Update',
        `There has been an update to the ${sheetName} sheet requiring your attention: ${url}`,
        {name: 'Team Leader'}
      ); 
    }
  }
}

